# Make page.tpl.php and page--front.tpl.php share same html

Tags: 7, theming

Is there a way to make `page.tpl.php` and `page--front.tpl.php` share the same template base?

If any of you are familiar with the Twig templating engine, You can define blocks with `{% block content %}Node Content{% endblock %}` and then do something like:

```
{% extends 'page.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}Home Page Stuff{% endblock %}
```

Does PHPTemplate have anything equivalent? I tried using PHP's `include()` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The theme system works by looking for templates that are a precise matches for the current path and then falling back to looking for less and less precise pages.

If you

1. delete your `page--front.tpl.php`
2. clear the cache

Then phptemplate should use `page.tpl.php` for your front page.

Answer (score 0):

Make a file, fe called page.shared.inc.php enter your shared code (html/php).

Then add the following to the page.tpl.php and page--front.tpl.php

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

PHP `include()` does work, and I bet I know why you're having trouble. Relative paths in `include()` are relative to the original script, not the file being included. So if you put `include('thingy.php')`, it's probably looking for it in the Drupal root directory next to `index.php`, not in your theme.

PHP's `__DIR__` constant returns the path to the current PHP file's directory, so if you do something like

```
<?php include(__DIR__ . '/thingy.php');
```

it ought to work. (Do remember to lead your path with a slash, as `__DIR__` does not end with one.